# Create inherit class of circle to show the scaling

Tags: c#, .net, console

I've got a task:
Make a console application to build the structure and functions which can:

a) input the circle parametres from keyboard/text file
b) output the circle parametres from keyboard/text file
c) calculate the square
d) calculate the length
e) do the automatic scaling of circle (function returns scaled copy of circle with changed radius (coordinates of centre of circle must not be changed)

So, as I understood, I need to create the circle object and make scaled copy using inheritance, but I honestly do not know how to realize this.

There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Task4_modified
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                        
            Circle circle1 = new Circle();

            circle1.DataInput(out double axisX1, out double axisY1, out double axisX2, out double axisY2);

            double radiusVector = circle1.VectorLength(axisX1, axisY1, axisX2, axisY2);
            double circleSquare = circle1.CircleSquare(radiusVector);
            double circleLength = circle1.CircleLength(radiusVector);

            Console.WriteLine($"\nCoordinates of radius-vector:\n x1: {axisX1}\t y1: {axisY1}\n x2: {axisX2}\t y2: {axisY2}\n");
            Console.WriteLine($" Coordinates of center: ({axisX1};{axisY1})\n Radius: {radiusVector}\n Square: {circleSquare}\n Length: {circleLength}\n ");

            Circle2 circle2 = new Circle2();

            circle1.Zooming(out double zoom);

           
            double zoomedRadius = circle1.ZoomingTheCricle(ref radiusVector, ref zoom);
            double zoomedCircleSquare = circle1.CircleSquare(zoomedRadius);
            double zoomedCircleLength = circle1.CircleLength(zoomedRadius);

            Console.WriteLine($"\nCoordinates of zoomed radius-vector:\n x1: {axisX1}\t y1: {axisY1}\n x2: {axisX2 * zoom}\t y2: {axisY2 * zoom}\n");
            Console.WriteLine($" Coordinates of center: ({axisX1};{axisY1})\n Zoomed radius: {zoomedRadius}\n Zoomed square: {zoomedCircleSquare}\n Zoomed length: {zoomedCircleLength}\n ");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        
    }

    class Circle
    {

        public double VectorLength(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
        {
            double stdVector = Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
            return stdVector;
        }
        public double CircleSquare(double r)
        {
            double square = r * r * Math.PI;
            return square;
        }

        public double CircleLength(double r)
        {
            double length = 2 * Math.PI * r;
            return length;
        }

        public double ZoomingTheCricle(ref double radiusVector, ref double zoom)
        {
            double zoomedRadiusVector = radiusVector * zoom;
            return zoomedRadiusVector;
        }
        public void DataInput(out double axisX1, out double axisY1, out double axisX2, out double axisY2)
        {
            const string UNDERLINE = "\x1B[4m";
            const string RESET = "\x1B[0m";
            Console.Write($"Press {UNDERLINE}F{RESET} to use file data input or press {UNDERLINE}ANY KEY{RESET} to input from keyboard: ");
            char check = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if (check == 'f')
            {
                Console.Write("Enter X1 coordinate: ");
                var temp_x1 = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!double.TryParse(temp_x1, out axisX1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
                    temp_x1 = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.Write("Enter Y1 coordinate: ");
                var temp_y1 = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!double.TryParse(temp_y1, out axisY1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
                    temp_y1 = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.Write("Enter X2 coordinate: ");
                var temp_x2 = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!double.TryParse(temp_x2, out axisX2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
                    temp_x2 = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                Console.Write("Enter Y2 coordinate: ");
                var temp_y2 = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!double.TryParse(temp_y2, out axisY2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
                    temp_y2 = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\nc_6d\source\repos\task4&5\Task4-5\Task4_modified\TextFile1.txt";
                using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);

                axisX1 = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
                axisY1 = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
                axisX2 = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
                axisY2 = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());

            }
        }
        public void Zooming(out double zoom)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter zoom factor: ");
            var temp_zoom = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!double.TryParse(temp_zoom, out zoom))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again");
                temp_zoom = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }

    class Circle2 : Circle
    {

        

    }

}
```

I started to learn C# about few weeks ago so I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your task completely, but here's my attempt.

It seems like inheritance is not really suited for your task, much rather you should simply create a new circle with the appropriately modified values.

This is a bit tricky with your current setup, because your circle class is essentially just providing the *methods* to handle circles, but doesn't actually store the properties.

I would suggest you re-write your current attempt, trying to stick to the following points:

#### Make sure you keep your IO logic out of the class.

The circle does not need to know how to receive input, or how to output the results. It - quite franky - just needs to know how to be a circle.

To achieve this, keep the circle as a sort of "data holder", allowing it to make the calculations it is relevant to, but don't make it receive input. Instead, serve to input to the circle in your `Main` method.

```cs
class Circle {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float radius;

    public double CalculateArea()
    {
       // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Once you do this, you'll find that it is pretty easy to create a new scaled version:

```cs
public Circle ScaleAsNew(double scale) {
    return new Circle {
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;
        radius = this.radius * scale;
    };
}
```

#### Avoid doubled code

Currently, a lot of your code is duplicated across your program, mainly the input receiving. While not a necessity, I'd advise you outsource this into a method, that takes a prompt for a variable and keeps trying to return a valid output until the user inputs one!

Hope I could help you!

Comment: There are a lot of useful advices for me as a newbie in C#, I will necessarily use it to improve my code, thanks!